# Web development using Python and Django with Sqlite3 (inbuilt db in Django)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, web-development-server

I am building a web based Dashboard using Django framework with Sqlite3 database (inbuilt DB that comes in Django).I'm Using HTML, CSS for first end designs and plotly library for data visualization. I would like to know about the scalability of this project. My concern is since I'm using inbuilt db sqlite3, will it sustain if we dump millions of records into this db? What is the maximum size of data it can accommodate?. I don't want to compromise my data visualization library plotly with this. I am planning to use this dashboard project for dumping millions of records on a daily/weekly basis. Can I continue with this db or do I have to migrate to other db's like postgres or mysql?

Comment: One of the first things the docs say is that the sqlite db will not be suitable for production.

Answer (score 0):

For production, I'd suggest you go for MySQL/MariaDB or PostgreSQL. SQLite isn't really suitable for production especially when you have a large number of hits. SQLite should do for a site with low traffic but isn't really scalable. You'll have to migrate to MySQL or PostgreSQL once you have higher traffic.